Proving that three proofs of transitivity of equality are equal in Homotopy Type Theory
This is the first exercise in the second chapter of HoTT book:

Show that the three obvious proofs of Lemma 2.1.2 are pairwise equal.

And lemma 2.1.2 is

For every type $A$ and every $x, y, z: A$, there is a function
$$(x=y) \to (y=z) \to (x=z),$$
written $p \mapsto q \mapsto p \cdot q$, such that $\mathrm{refl}_x \cdot \mathrm{refl}_x \equiv \mathrm{refl}_x$ for any $x:A$.

The three obvious proofs are path induction over $x=y$, path induction over $y=z$ and two path inductions over both of these paths. Depending on the proof, we will also get a different computation rule: $\mathrm{refl}_y\cdot q \equiv q$ for induction over $x=y$ and $p \cdot \mathrm{refl}_y \equiv p$ for induction over $y=z$, so I assume this part is not actually part of the proposition whose proofs we have to prove equal.
I understand the statement of the theorem, the proofs and the fact that the proofs themselves are also objects which can be propositionally equal. However, I have no idea how to prove this.
I also have a side question. This is also probably the first time that after reading a chapter of a textbook I'm completely lost on the first exercise and have no idea on how to approach it. The first chapter of the book was fine, I was able to do most of the exercises without any problems. But with the second chapter, although I think I'm getting the big picture, the details are going completely over my head, even after re-reading a big chunk of it. I have background in topology (Munkres), category theory (Awodey) and some type theory (first two volumes of Software Foundations), so I'd think this is enough for starting HoTT. I know this is not the easiest subject, but still, is that expected? Should I just continue on to the next chapter to get some higher-lever exposure of the theory and go back to the second chapter later?

You're trying to prove a statement of the form $\Pi_{p : x = y} \Pi_{q : y = z} \cdots$. Do you know of any principles that might help you with that? (Hint: you do.)

I don't really see how the statement is of this form. Lemma 2.1.2, assuming that $A, x, y, z$ are set, is of the form $(x=y)\to(y=z)\to(x=z)$. Now, if we denote the three proofs by $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, aren't we trying to prove $\alpha ={(x=y)\to(y=z)\to(x=z)} \beta$ and $\beta ={(x=y)\to(y=z)\to(x=z)} \gamma$?

Fair enough. Well, what do you know about paths between functions? (Hint: §2.9)

Well, if we assume the axiom of function extensionality, then it would suffice to show that for every path $p:x=y$, we have $\alpha(p)=_{(=)→(=)}\beta(p)$. To show this, we can assume $p \equiv \mathrm{refl}_x$ (as your first comment suggested), and we are left with $\alpha(\mathrm{refl}x)={(=)→(=)}\beta(\mathrm{refl}_x)$, which can be proven by using function extensionality and path induction again.
But it does feel a little bit like cheating. The fact that this is an easy proof was mentioned before the axiom was introduced. Is it possible to do this without it?

The heart of the exercise is to prove that $\alpha(p, q) = \beta(p, q)$ for all paths $p$ and $q$, which is an easy proof by path induction. You don't need to interpret it literally as asking for a proof that $\alpha = \beta$, although that straightforwardly follows from function extensionality.
